# Connecting Signal GND to PE

Tags: power-supply, ground

Currently I'm working at equipment containing AC-DC power supply & digital processing board inside same enclosure. I don't have any experience with AC powered devices, so I have a question. According to safety requirement I should connect PE conductor to aluminium enclosure. Is it a common practice also to connect digital ground to the enclosure? In this case PE = DGND (0VD), is any issue here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do not connect it, keep it floating. If there will be connection to other grounded source, like audio, quite substantial currents can flow through your 0 V to thé ground. If you are afraid od inducted voltage you can use high ohmic grounding.

Yes https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthing_system

Answer (score 0):

If your strictly running digital electronics, they will run fine with an isolated supply and not being grounded to the chassis. It makes little difference to the digital electronics if they are grounded or not. I run many of my products this way. As far as I understand there are no requirements that you should do so (or I would have been yelled at during testing in regulatory).

The advantage of grounding would be to allow electric fields emitted by the board to return back to the source which may be useful for EMC.

If there are cables running to a separate unit, you may have difficulty passing the unintentional radiators FCC testing. It may then become better to ground the electronics, or it might not. This must be evaluated on a case by case basis.

Comment: As for me I also see more sense in fully isolated systems. But I worry a little about having floating voltages in case of using multiple devices at same time. As for me safety is the only reason to have DGND to enclosure connection.

Comment: Do you have anything running out of the digital board?

Comment: Yes, one isolated differential RS422 channel for communication with PC for updating firmware and one isolated (using ADuM1201 digital isolator) single ended UART (rx & tx lines) for communication with similar devices. But this interfaces could be or could be not connected.